# Azuresearch search.in functionallity not working as expected

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search

Trying to figure out why the following filter returns different results.

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters) i should be able to use the `and or` condition with the `search in` function

> search.in(f, ‘a, b, c’) is semantically equivalent to f eq ‘a’ or f eq
>   ‘b’ or f eq ‘c’, except that it executes much faster when the list of
>   values is large.

But the following filters returns different results. But why?

```
   // Returns nothing
   $count=true&$filter=companyGroupId eq 1595 and search.in(companyName, 'Sky Blue, Green Ice')
```

But if i do it this way

```
   // Returns expected results
    $count=true&$filter=companyGroupId eq 1595 and (companyName eq 'Sky Blue' or companyName eq 'Green Ice')
```

Why are the results so different to me it seems like they should be the same.

My CompanyName Property looks like this

```
[IsFilterable]
[IsSortable]
[IsFacetable]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different because of the way `search.in` parses the second parameter. Since your values have spaces in them, you'll need to specify your own separator as a third parameter to `search.in`. The default behavior is to break on spaces and commas. Try this instead:

`search.in(companyName, 'Sky Blue|Green Ice', '|')`

You can find other examples of using `search.in` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search#filter-examples).

Comment: That is true, but should the search.in not handle the parentheses? How should the search.in filter look then. $count=true&$filter=companyGroupId eq 1595 and (search.in(companyName, 'Sky Blue, Green Ice')) ? because that also does not work

Comment: I added the parentheses around the second filter. but like I mentioned in the above comment the search.in result is not returning anything, and to me, those 2 queries should be the same result.

Comment: @R4nc1d The parens don't fix the problem because there is a second issue that I missed. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Let me know if it helps.